# Pulling the postcode area from the full postcode

Tags: javascript

If I have a Postcode `EH1 2GB` I am looking for a function which will pull only the `EH`

Ideally this would work for postcodes which may only contain 1 leading letter such as `G2 1AB` and 2 numbers after the leading letters such as `EH54 1BD` and `G25 2RD`

I have tried using

`Postcode.match(/[a-zA-Z]+|[0-9]+/g)`

However when used with `EH1 2GB` The result I get is `["EH", "1", "2", "GB"]` Ideally this would be fither simplified to return only `EH`

Is there an efficient way to acheive this?

Comment: _"may only contain 1 leading letter such as G2 1AB"_ - and from that you would want what then - `G`, or `G2`?

Comment: Just use the first element in the returned array?

Comment: @CBroe I only want the letters from the first part - `G`, `EH` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `^` (line start) expression and only select the initial letters.

```js
const extractPostalArea = (postalCode) => postalCode.match(/^[A-Z]+/)?.[0] ?? null;

console.log(extractPostalArea('EH1 2GB'));  // EH
console.log(extractPostalArea('G2 1AB'));   // G
console.log(extractPostalArea('EH54 1BD')); // EH
console.log(extractPostalArea('G25 2RD'));  // G
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```